# Django CMS page_attribute falls back to other values?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm currently editing the base template that all my Django-CMS templates inherit from. What I'm trying to do is printing the *page_title* attribute, and if that hasn't been set, print `{{ block.super }}` instead.

My current code is this:

```
{% block title %}
    {% page_attribute "page_title" as cms_title %}

    {% if cms_title and cms_title.strip %}
        {{ cms_title }}
    {% else %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now, when the page title property is set, this works as expected. However, when the page title is left blank, the page's title attribute is used instead which I wouldn't expect.

Is this expected behaviour? If it is, how can I work around this? Or is there another approach to get the result I want?

I'm using Django-CMS 3.0

**Edit**

I've been told that this is expected behaviour, but no workaround was provided. The solution that was good enough for my situation was to compare the `page_title` and `title` attributes. If they're equal, the `title` is probably being used as a fallback so I could assume the `page_title` wasn't set.

If anyone has a better suggestion, feel free to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just given this a go & you can conditionally override the block like so;

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load i18n cms_tags %}
{% page_attribute "page_title" as cms_title %}

{% if cms_title %}
    {% block title %}
        {{ cms_title }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```